# C code autocomplete in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, autocomplete

I'm a Java developer and I've downloaded the Eclipse for C (course purposes) and to my amazement the control+space shortcut (for autocomplete) did not work.
I've created a new project and a new class using the wizzards and started to type "print" and then tried to find an autocomplete feature.
After a bit of googling I arrived at `C/C++`->`Editor`->`Content Assist`->`Advanced` and there  I verified that `Help proposals`,`Parsing-based proposals` and `Template proposals` options were checked.
I then went over to the `Keys` preferences page using the link at that page and entered a binding for all relevant content assist from before `C\C++ Content Assist (type...)` and chose in the `When` box the `C\C++ Editor` option.
But alas no autocompletion was offered.
Can someone please point me to the right direction?

**UPDATE:** I'm accepting the answer not because I'm sure it's right but because I've realised I've made some mistakes with the configuration of the eclipse and have seen that with another installation/configuration (i.e. a friend of mines) eclipse does auto complete, even if it still lack many of the java version features.

Comment: Hello, I have this problem too but Ittai didn't mention exactly what mistakes he'd done.

Comment: @badp I've posted an answer specifying what I did

Comment: You should accept your answer not an answer and comment that it does not work !!!!!

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D the accepted answer led me to the complete solution and it is correct in essence. see my update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the eclipse doesn't provide perfect auto-complete, but it works..
This sometimes happens when you have the indexer turned off.

Try to enable the indexer and rebuild the index.

See this question in [CDT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Why_does_Open_Declaration_.28F3.29_not_work.3F_.28also_applies_to_other_functions_using_the_indexer.29). It contains info about how to find indexer error which might prevent auto-complete.

Answer (score 7):

Use the Advanced panel in the Preferences window to configure the behavior of the Content Assist (Ctrl+Space) command. 
Go to **Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced**. 
Check the **parsing-based-Proposals** in Default Proposal kinds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Eclipse expert (and I don't even play one on TV), but it might be that it only autocompletes function names that are declared in the current scope - have you added `#include <stdio.h>` to the top of your source file to get the declarations for the standard I/O functions?

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that you have the gcc home (i.e. C:\MinGW-4.4.1\bin) defined in the path environment variable (if you're using windows and if not then it's equivelant). Also verify that the file has a .c suffix and that the indexer is on as yousf said.
I think, not sure, that you need to then run eclipse with the -clean flag and the autocomplete will work.

Ittai

Answer (score 0):

i answered it here: 
[Eclipse: How to add include path to be used by autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650811/eclipse-how-to-add-include-path-to-be-used-by-autocompletion/23136667#23136667)

> You have to explicitly tell it where to find the header:
>
> ⇒ Right click on your project 
>  ⇒ go to 'C/C++ Include Paths and
>   Symbols' 
>   ⇒ select 'Add External Include Path...' 
>  ⇒ browse
>   to the location of your header files 
>  ⇒ refresh

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is related with KeyAssist bindings.

If you have tried with content assist:

Enter into **Window > Preferences. Menu "General" -> "Keys"**

Inside search for **"Template"** and set:

Key **Binding to -> "Ctrl + Space"**

When: **"Editing Test"**

Image helper [Image Menu Key Assist Code Complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw7QI.png)

Answer (score -2):

Vim offers this functionality by scanning your #include's (the shortcut is Ctrl-N, or Ctrl-P to search backwards).  If you can't find any better solution, one last resort could be looking into [eclim](http://www.eclim.org), which integrates vim features into Eclipse (or vice-versa), and that's sure to offer this feature.