# Eclipse: How to add include path to be used by autocompletion

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, autocomplete

I am playing around with Linux device drivers. And I've noticed that eclipse doesn't do any auto-completion. Even though the include paths, Eclipse fails to show any autocompletion.

Is there a way to point Eclipse to a directory and tell it to build index of it?

Comment: which programing language used?

Comment: I'm not sure about C, but in java Eclipse indexes classpath set in project's properties(Alt-Enter on project folder).

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly tell it where to find the header:

⇒ Right click on your project  
⇒ go to '*C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols*' 
⇒ select *'Add External Include Path...'* 
⇒ browse to the location of your header files 
⇒ refresh

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Spacebar is the shortcut for auto-completion in Eclipse.